# NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I recently downloaded PyCharm and installed Python 3.6 into terminal. That worked successfully but the issue is that while I'm attempting to run files from the text editor (PyCharm)in terminal using the command line as I'm practicing coding, I get the error "no such file or directory." Did I install something wrong? If someone could correct my mistake or guide me to a proper installation guide that'd be great. [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPp80.png)

Comment: Do you have a file called `script1.py` in the current directory where the terminal is?

Comment: I'm not sure, how could I check?

Comment: `ls -l` in the same place where you typed `python script1.py`

Comment: Hi Your file is not at right location you can check it using pwd or ls
Use the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + R on Mac to run file directly

Comment: All that was returned are folders, so I'm assuming no.

Comment: Type open . in your terminal and check if there is your file is there or not else create new file or move your file here and use shortcut key to run.

Comment: @PallavChanana Is it possible to give terminal access to the directory where I keep my files? So that I can run files from the command line?

Comment: Yes it is possible you can run using terminal you just need to use command python3 "pathOfYourFile/filename" or go at that location of file and run using python3 filename.py

Comment: @PallavChanana I see what the issue is. Terminal is working with Python 2.7 instead of  3.6. The error I got by trying it your way is "permission denied." Then I tried it without the 3 and it worked.

Comment: @triedit If you are using older python version you can use only python filename.py
to run file.

Comment: How can I upgrade terminal to run python 3 by default and then respond the way the 2.7 version did?

Comment: @triedit  You need to configure interpreter setting in pycharm Follow this [Updated Ref](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)

Comment: @triedit if you get your answers Please upvote that will help other to find solution Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out where you saved your file. If you don't remember it, don't worry just go to PyCharm and find out. Or use Search to find it.

Once you know exactly where the file is, go to the terminal and type:

```
% cd path/to/the/folder/where/the/file/is/saved
% python script1.py
```

The problem is that the terminal is currently in a different folder. Think of it as though it were the file manager. If you are in Documents while the file is in Downloads you can't really open that file. Similarly, you need to cd (change directory) to the folder where the file is saved in order to run it.